# jQuery - 3 minutes in seconds

Tags: jquery, timer, timeout, seconds, minute

I thought this would be easy, but seems i either to way to short or way to long.

I am trying to make it sign the user out after 3minutes 
this is the count down I thought would work I have tried 3000, 300, 3*60, 3*1000 and so on

```
var timeout = 30*1800;
```

This is the function I am trying to run,

```
    function loadidle(){

          var timeout = 180000;
          //alert(timeout);

          $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){

              logout();

          });


          $.idleTimer(timeout);
}
```

Comment: 1000*60*3 (1000 miliseconds, times 60 seconds, times 3 minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple timer. There are many varieties. Here's a dirt cheap example that abstracts it nicely as a class. You can "continue" the timer by calling .reset().

```
function Timeout(seconds, callback){
    this.length = seconds * 1000;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.start();
}
Timeout.prototype = {
    start: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.stop();
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
            self.complete();
        },this.length);
    },
    stop: function(){
        if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
    },
    complete: function(){
        if (this.callback) this.callback();
        this.stop();
    },
    reset: function() {
        this.stop();
        this.start();
    }
}
```

Start a new timer:

```
var timer = new Timeout(3 * 60, logout);
timer.reset(); // refresh the timer
timer.stop(); // cancel the timer
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure JS (and therefore jQuery) use milliseconds, so you'll be wanting 3*60*1000.

Comment: While I'm at it, using 'seconds' and 'minute' as tags isn't really best practice!